# Use data as post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http-post

I have one form in PHP, where I can dynamically add or remove rows using jquery for that, with select boxes. So when I click in a button to add another row, I added the content using the `.after` method.

For example:

```
var cnt_class = 2;
var count = 1;

// adiciona classe
$("#add_line_class").click(function(){
    $("#tbl_add_class tr").last().after('<tr><td><strong>Classe:</strong>&nbsp;<select name="classe_letter['+count+']" id="classe_letter"><?php while(!$rs_main_class->EOF) { ?><option value="<?=$rs_main_class->Fields("class")?>"><?=$rs_main_class->Fields("class")?></option><?php $rs_main_class->MoveNext(); } $rs_main_class->MoveFirst(); ?></select></td><td><strong>Lugares:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="class_pax['+count+']" id="class_pax" value="0" size="5"></td></tr>');
alert(class_letter[1]);
    cnt_class++;
    count++;
});
```

What I pretend is retrieve the values of select box (by the name class_letter). By doing the post of PHP, the jQuery normally I think doesn't pass the values through the post. Should I use a normal post via ajax? Or there is some easier way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure how you submit that form, but I already see that you should watch out: there will be multiple select elements with the same id, which is forbidden, you better add that count to id as well: `id="classe_letter'+count+'"`

Comment: Can you add a bit more code/html? Please show how your form is setup.

Comment: I think that's is correct because I've checked with firebug and it passes well the id, I mean, classe_letter[1], classe_letter[2], etc.

Comment: I edited the code above.